# Application missing in applications settings list in iOS

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm building an application and I find out that my app is not listed in iOS settings.
It is listed in the applications that uses the location but that's about it. You can see in the locations settings the Pearl app is listed. Do I have to do something special to have a settings page in iOS?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try killing Settings app and reopening it? Might be a bug.

Comment: Yes I did after finding some people commenting this in different posts but that didn't work.